# Trying to understand dplyr function - group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to understand the way `group_by` function works in `dplyr`. I am using the `airquality` data set, that comes with the `datasets` package [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/airquality.html).

I understand that is if I do the following, it should arrange the records in increasing order of `Temp` variable

```
airquality_max1 <- airquality %>% arrange(Temp)
```

I see that is the case in `airquality_max1`. I now want to arrange the records by increasing order of `Temp` but grouped by `Month`. So the end result should first have all the records for `Month == 5` in increasing order of `Temp`. Then it should have all records of `Month == 6` in increasing order of `Temp` and so on, so I use the following command

```
airquality_max2 <- airquality %>% group_by(Month) %>% arrange(Temp)
```

However, what I find is that the results are still in increasing order of `Temp` only, not grouped by `Month`, i.e., `airquality_max1` and `airquality_max2` are equal.

I am not sure why the grouping by `Month` does not happen before the `arrange` function. Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

More than the problem of trying to sort the data frame by columns, I am trying to understand the behavior of `group_by` as I am trying to use this to explain the application of `group_by` to someone.

Comment: Maybe you also need to add `Month` parameter in `arrange`. `airquality_max2 <- airquality %>% arrange(Month, Temp)`

Comment: sorting is not an aggregation, so there's no need to use `group_by`...

Comment: I was trying to use this as a pedantic example to show the application of `group_by` but was stumbled to find this behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a dataframe by column(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arrange` ignores `group_by`, see [break-changes](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/06/27/dplyr-0-5-0/#breaking-changes) on dplyr 0.5.0. If you need to order by two columns, you can do:

```
airquality %>% arrange(Month, Temp)
```

For grouped data frame, you can also `.by_group` variable to *sort by the group variable first*.

```
airquality %>% group_by(Month) %>% arrange(Temp, .by_group = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. The link is helpful, this behavior is counter-intuitive but as long it doesn't change again, it's okay.

Comment: `airquality %>% group_by(Month) %>% arrange(Temp, .by_group = TRUE)` gives me an error. `Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : incorrect size (1), expecting : 153` any idea why?

Comment: You may think you need to sort by a group variable, but usually you don't, as long as the sorting algorithm is stable (which I believe they are), you can either do `group_by %>% arrange` or `arrange %>% group_by`. `group_by` by itself will sort the data frame by the group variable. So effectively you are still sorting the data frame by both the group variable and the sorting variable even you didn't explicitly tell it to.

Comment: @RonakShah I am not sure. It seems to run fine on my machine.

Comment: @RonakShah - I got the error, the first time, ran it again and it worked fine.